# Simulating a select event with Enzyme

Tags: enzyme

I am a little confused because this seems to be such a trivial and easy thing, yet there is hardly any proper documentation in Enzyme on how to do this.

I want to do one of the simplest things in the world. I just want to simulate a select event in a drop down select (HTML select/combo) by selecting an option called "dogs".

When I have this option selected would like to see that the option is "selected", and I would also like to see that the select **value** is set to "dogs".

What am I doing wrong here?

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow, mount} from "enzyme"

    test(' change  ', () => {
        let Compoment =
            <select className="sel" name="selectComp" required="">
                <option value="empty">Please make your choice ...</option>
                <option value="cats">feline</option>
                <option value="dogs">canine</option>
            </select>;

        const wrapper = mount(Compoment);

        let sel = wrapper.find(".sel").at(0)
        sel.simulate('change', { target: { name: 'selectComp', value: "dogs" } });

        expect(wrapper.find(".sel").at(0).getElement().value).toBe("dogs")
        expect(wrapper.find(".sel").at(0).find("option").at(2).props().selected).toBe(true)
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

React syncs prop=>DOM property only one way.

If you set `selected` prop on `<option>` element React would write it into DOM `selected` property(but you actually don't use `selected` prop at all).

You browser(or JSDOM in case of Jest tests) also changes `selected` property for relevant `<option>` element upon user selection.

So that's why `prop` does not reflect change.

You can use [`getDOMNode`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/getDOMNode.html) to access underlying DOM node:

```
expect(wrapper.find(".sel").at(0).find("option").at(2).getDOMNode().selected).toBe(true)
```

but know what? you don't need that. This would just test browser highlights right option upon user selection. It's just a wasted time to check if browser and/or React do their job responsibly.